# Lists of coefficients of derivatives

Tags: factorization

I want to extract two separate lists of coefficients of derivatives. If I have, for example,

```
cl= A1*D[P[x, y], {x, 1}] + A2*D[P[x, y], {x, 2}] + 
    A3*D[Q[x, y], {y, 3}] + A4*D[Q[x, y], {y, 1}];
```

I want to extract the lists `{A1, A2}` and `{A3, A4}` but do not want to type all the derivative expressions into command `CoefficientList`. I want to extract these lists programmatically because of I have a very long list of derivatives in my actual problem, which I thought was too long to post here.

The following seems to work, but how can I do it without typing in the list of derivatives?

```
Coefficient[cl, {D[P[x, y], {x, 1}], D[P[x, y], {x, 2}]}]
Coefficient[cl, {D[Q[x, y], {y, 3}], D[Q[x, y], {y, 1}]}]
```

Longer example

```
 cl2=B1*Derivative[0, 1, 0][R][x, y, z] + 
 B2*Derivative[2, 0, 0][R][x, y, z] + 
 B4*Derivative[2, 1, 3][V][x, y, z] + 
 B3*Derivative[3, 2, 1][R][x, y, z] + B5*Derivative[4, 1, 5][V][x, y, z] + B0*V[x, y, z]  + B00*R[x, y, z];
```

I need list of coefficients and list of derivatives parallel to know for which derivative is appropriate coefficient. But if I have zero derivatives, they don't appear in the list?

Comment: @Nasser It is managed now. Please try it, I think it is working, but how to do that without typing for which derivatives I want coefficient in front. I need it all. For example CoefficientList[cl,derivatives]??

Comment: Use Cases to extract the set(s) of variables of interest. `Coefficient[cl, 
 Cases[Variables[cl], HoldPattern[Derivative[__][P][__]]]]`

Out: `{A1, A2}`

Comment: @Daniel Thank you Daniel

Comment: I see you updated your question again.  In the future please try your best to communicate what you need from the beginning so that it does not take as many cycles to get there.  Does this perform as you desire? `Reap[Cases[cl3, coef_*d : Derivative[__][_][__] :> Sow[coef, d], 
   1], _, {#, Total@#2} &][[2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also borrowing from Daniel's comment, perhaps you would like:

```
cl = A1*D[P[x, y], {x, 1}] + A2*D[P[x, y], {x, 2}] + 
     A3*D[Q[x, y], {y, 3}] + A4*D[Q[x, y], {y, 1}];

Cases[cl, coef_ * Derivative[__][x_][__] :> {x, coef}, 1];

{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[%, First]
```

> ```
> {{Q, {A4, A3}}, {P, {A1, A2}}}
> ```

Or somewhat less transparently as a one-liner:

```
Reap[Cases[cl, coef_*Derivative[__][x_][__] :> Sow[coef, x], 1], _, List][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{Q, {A4, A3}}, {P, {A1, A2}}}
> ```

---

Based on the comments below I believe you may use:

```
Reap[Cases[cl2, coef_ * d : Derivative[__][_][__] :> Sow[coef, d], 1], _, List][[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for your attention but how to know which coefficient is with which derivative? If I will have partial derivatives, I need list of derivatives and list of coefficients parallel to know how to pair them.

Comment: @Pipe please give me a longer example of desired input and output.

Comment: @ longer example is in input question

Comment: @Pipe Thanks, but what output do you desire?  It's still not clear to me what information you need to extract and how you want them grouped.

Comment: @Wizard I want all derivatives and all appropriate coefficients. To know order with which derivative is which coefficient

Comment: @Pipe so for your example would this be good output?: `{{{R, 0, 1, 0}, {B1}}, {{R, 2, 0, 0}, {B2}}, {{V, 2, 1, 
   3}, {B4}}, {{R, 3, 2, 1}, {B3}}, {{V, 4, 1, 5}, {B5}}}` -- or maybe: `{{Derivative[0, 1, 0][R][x, y, z], {B1}}, {Derivative[2, 0, 0][R][x, y, z], {B2}}, 
 {Derivative[2, 1, 3][V][x, y, z], {B4}}, {Derivative[3, 2, 1][R][x, y, z], {B3}}, 
 {Derivative[4, 1, 5][V][x, y, z], {B5}}}`?  I'm not trying to be obtuse.

Comment: Wizard {{Derivative[0, 1, 0][R][x, y, z], {B1}}, {Derivative[2, 0, 0][R][x, y, z], {B2}}, {Derivative[2, 1, 3][V][x, y, z], {B4}}, {Derivative[3, 2, 1][R][x, y, z], {B3}}, {Derivative[4, 1, 5][V][x, y, z], {B5}}} is clear and perfect answer what I actually wanted.

Comment: @Pipe please see my updated answer

Comment: the problem is if I have repeated derivatives in the equation then the output does not collect it together. Please see updated example cl3 in question.

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard Thank you very much for your answer, but the problem is if I have zero derivatives, in that case I will have just functions and I want to see also coefficients with them in the list, please see cl2

Comment: @Pipe Does `Reap[Cases[cl2, 
   coef_*d : Derivative[__][_][__] | _[__] :> Sow[coef, d], 1], _, 
  List][[2]]` do what you want?  The more general this pattern is (and this one is *quite* general) the greater the possibility for false matches, but without a more *complete* specification of your problem as to what is and is not a match this is all I can recommend.

Comment: Wizard thank you very much... suggestion is very good and that's it, working very well.

Answer (score 1):

Turning Daniel's comment into an answer:

> This is working, but how to do that not to type list of derivatives

You can do this by extracting the list you are currently type automatically. In the first list, you want all derivates wrt `P`. If you look at the `FullForm` you instantly see how such a derivative is represented internally

```
D[P[x,y],{x,2}]//FullForm

(* Derivative[2,0][P][x,y] *)
```

Important for you is only the `P` inside this form. Therefore, you create a pattern where everything else can be *anything*. This is done with `Blank` (`_`) or `BlankSequence` (`__`). For the extraction you use `Cases`

```
Cases[cl, Derivative[__][P][__], Infinity]

(* {(P^(1,0))[x,y],(P^(2,0))[x,y]} *)
```

This list can now be used inside `Coefficient`

```
Coefficient[cl, Cases[cl,Derivative[__][P][__],Infinity]]
(* {A1,A2} *)
```

### Further reading

It should be obvious, that you can turn this immediately into a function where you only give the differential form and the variable

```
deqCoeffitient[deq_, var_Symbol] := 
 Coefficient[deq, Cases[Variables[deq], Derivative[__][var][__]]];
deqCoeffitient[cl,Q]
(* {A4,A3} *)
```

To make this more robust, you should definitely read in the documentation about [Patterns and Transformation Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html).

Comment: how to know which coefficient is with which order of derivatives? Maybe it is better to print list of coefficients and list of derivatives. I need some help about code.