# Coefficient Array from total derivative of expression

Tags: differential-equations, coefficients

I have an expression $$\dot{r}\dot{\eta}+r^{2}\dot{\theta}\dot{\xi}=0$$ where $\eta$ and $\xi$ are both functions of $r,\theta$. In MM I wrote this as

```
de = Dt[r, t] Dt[eta[r, th], t] + r^2 Dt[th, t] Dt[xi[r, th], t]
```

What I wish to do now is solve this equation by separating it into a set of PDEs for each power of $\dot{r}, \dot{\theta}$ and then integrating each to find the functions $\xi,\eta$. What I need is an equivalent of CoefficientArrays for each power of the co-ordinate derivatives.

For instance, the $\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$ term would be $$ \eta_{\theta} +r^2\xi_r$$ where the subscript denotes partial differentiation. Is there a way to do this? I tried the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/lists-of-coefficients-of-derivatives) but couldn't get it to work for my purposes. Thank you!

***EDIT:*** The answer provided by @kglr works perfectly! Simply `Normal@Rest@CoefficientArrays[de, {Dt[r, t] , Dt[th, t]}]` which for some reason I couldn't get to work.

As an extension to this problem, what happens if `xi` and `eta` are also functions of `Dt[r,t]` and `Dt[th,t]`? Now coefficient array returns the error "not a polynomial" because it is trying to pattern match inside the functions when I don't want it to. Any ideas?

P.S the `Dt[r,{t,2}]` and `Dt[th,{t,2}]` terms that result can be ignored because in practise they are replaced by their respective equations of motion which are functions of `Dt[r,t]` and `Dt[th,t]`. For all intents and purposes we can simply use a replace rule to set `Dt[r,{t,2}]` and `Dt[th,{t,2}]` equal to 0.

Comment: `Normal@Rest@CoefficientArrays[de, {Dt[r, t] , Dt[th, t]}]`?

Comment: .. or `Normal@Rest@
  CoefficientArrays[de, {Dt[r, t] , Dt[th, t], Dt[eta, t], Dt[xi, t]}]?`

Comment: @kglr That seems to work! I have no idea why what I was doing before didn't... Anyway I am going to extend this question a bit: What happens if `xi` and `eta` are also functions of `Dt[r,t]` and `Dt[th,t]`? Now coefficient array returns the error "not a polynomial" because it is trying to pattern match inside the functions when I don't want it to. Any ideas? I will edit my question with your answer and this followup.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use `CoefficientList`.

```
CoefficientList[de, {Dt[r, t], Dt[th, t]}] //ColumnForm
```

gives the associated PDEs in each power of your co-ordinate velocities. Then all you need to do is `Flatten` and `DeleteCases` of 0 and you get a system of PDEs that you can solve.

```
DeleteCases[CoefficientList[de, {Dt[r, t], Dt[th, t]}], 0, Infinity] // Flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

Re:

> As an extension to this problem, what happens if `xi` and `eta` are also functions of `Dt[r,t]` and `Dt[th,t]`?

I take this to mean:

```
de = Dt[r, t] Dt[eta[r, th, Dt[r, t], Dt[th, t]], t] + 
  r^2 Dt[th, t] Dt[xi[r, th, Dt[r, t], Dt[th, t]], t]
```

The expression `Dt[r, t]` as an argument to `eta` etc. means `de` is not a polynomial in `Dt[r, t]`. Interpreting the OP's intention to be to treat the derivatives of `eta[r, th, Dt[r, t], Dt[th, t]]` as independent of `Dt[r, t]` for the purposes of treating `de` as a polynomial in `Dt[r, t]` and `Dt[th, t]`, the easiest approach seems to be to replace the arguments of `eta` and `xi` by new temporary, independent variables, get the coefficient, and then back substitute the original arguments for the temporary variables:

```
Block[{f},
 vars = List @@ eta[r, th, Dt[r, t], Dt[th, t]];
 tempvars = Unique["vars", Temporary] & /@ vars;
 vars2temp = Pattern[f, Blank[]] @@ vars :> Evaluate[f @@ tempvars];
 temp2vars = Pattern[f, Blank[]] @@ tempvars :> Evaluate[f @@ vars];
 ]
```

If you want all derivatives of `r` and `th` to be treated as variables in `de`:

```
ca = Normal@CoefficientArrays[de /. vars2temp, Dt[vars, t]] /. 
  temp2vars
```

But the OP said that only the first derivatives are to be considered variables in `de`:

```
ca = Normal@CoefficientArrays[de /. vars2temp, Dt[{r, th}, t]] /. 
  temp2vars
```

[image]